# Problem with geometryFunction for draw interaction

Tags: javascript, geometry, openlayers

I'm using geometryFunction in draw interaction to change geometry coords of current drawing and I'm also using styling function for handling labels etc.

The problem is that style function gets couple features to handle while drawing but geometryFunction returns only one.

For instance when I'm drawing LineString, geometryFunction returns modified LineString geometry, but style handles 2 features with Point and LineString geometry so feature with Point geometry is not modified.

Same when drawing Polygon: style function handles Point, LineString and Polygon features, but geometryFunction returns only Polygon geometry and in style function only feature with Polygon geometry is modified.

I've tried many ways of changing geometries in style function, but it didn't work as expected.

The question is how to handle coordinate change on pointermove for all features while using draw interaction?

This is my geometryFunction:

```js
const obliqueGeom = (coords, geom) => {
  const center = this.obliCoords[0];
  const last = this.obliCoords[this.obliCoords.length - 1];
  const dx = center[0] - last[0];
  const dy = center[1] - last[1];
  const radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

  if (!geom) {
    if (measureType === "LineString") {
      geom = new ol.geom.LineString(this.obliCoords)
    }
    if (measureType === "Polygon") {
      geom = new ol.geom.Polygon([this.obliCoords])
    }
    if (measureType === "Circle") {
      geom = new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius)
    }
    if (measureType === "Point") {
      geom = new ol.geom.Point(this.obliCoords)
    }
  } else {
    if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Circle) {
      geom.setCenterAndRadius(center, radius)
    } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
      geom.setCoordinates([this.obliCoords])
    } else {
      geom.setCoordinates(this.obliCoords)
    }
  }

  return geom
}
```

That's how I'm collecting coords:

```js
this.clickEvt = this.map.on("click", (evt) => {
  newPx = [evt.pixel[0], evt.pixel[1] / 0.83]
  newCoord = this.map.getCoordinateFromPixel(newPx)
  if (measureType !== "Polygon") {
    this.obliCoords.push(newCoord)
  } else {
    if (this.obliCoords.length <= 1) {
      this.obliCoords.splice(0, 0, newCoord)
      this.obliCoords.push(newCoord)
    } else {
      this.obliCoords.splice(this.obliCoords.length - 1, 0, newCoord)
    }
  }
})

this.moveEvt = this.map.on("pointermove", (evt) => {
  newPx = [evt.pixel[0], evt.pixel[1] / 0.83]
  newCoord = this.map.getCoordinateFromPixel(newPx)
  if (measureType !== "Polygon") {
    this.obliCoords.pop()
    this.obliCoords.push(newCoord)
  } else {
    if (this.obliCoords.length <= 1) {
      this.obliCoords.pop()
      this.obliCoords.push(newCoord)
    } else {
      this.obliCoords.splice(this.obliCoords.length - 2, 1, newCoord)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the `type` specified when constructing the interaction the interaction's overlay will have up to 3 features `draw.getOverlay().getSource().getFeatures().length`  One will have the geometry returned by the geometry function, one will have a point geometry using the final coordinate passed to the geometry function (the pointer position), and in the case of polygon type one will be a linestring feature made from the input cooordinates to the geometry function.  In a custom style function you might wnat to ignore some geometry types, and if the polygon has been modified by the geometry function return an array of styles based on that to substitute for the auto-generated features which no longer match the polygon, for example

```
function(feature) {
  const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
  if (geometry.getType() == 'Polygon') {
    const coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates()[0];
    return [
      new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
          color: fillColor
        })
      }),
      new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
          width: 2,
          color: strokeColor
        }),
        geometry: new LineString(coordinates.slice(0, -1))
      }),
      new Style({
        image: new CircleStyle({
          radius: 5,
          fill: circleFill,
          stroke: circleStroke
        }),
        geometry: new Point(coordinates[coordinates.length - 2])
      })
    ];
  }
}
```

Note that you should close a polygon

```
geom = new ol.geom.Polygon([this.obliCoords.concat([this.obliCoords[0]])])
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! That explains a lot!

I've already partly solved my problem by creating, updating and cloning every geometry in my eventHandlers and then setting them as geometries for specific features in my style function but there are still some issues with appropriate label positioning etc.

Your way seems much better for doing what I want to achieve and I'll definitely make use of it.

P.S. I'm closing polygon in my events handlers by splicing obliCoords.
P.S.2. My next step is handling select interaction with dislocated pointer. Can you give me any clues how to do that? :D